# How to update notification continuously in ionic app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am looking for ways to run my app in background mode. 
I have used the following [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) for my ionic app.

My requirement is that I have to update the text part of the notification repeatedly every second. Here is a part of my code.

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ 
    title : 'Timer running',
    text  : 'some text'
});
```

I have updated the text part using the configure method.

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        a = a + 1;
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.configure({
            text: a
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

The text part is updating properly. But the notification is created each time the text part is updated.

Is there any method that can be used to update just the text and not load the whole notification?
Or would any other plugin provide the required functionalities?